# Submitting data in a Livewire child view using its <form> in the parent view

Tags: php, arrays, laravel, laravel-blade, laravel-livewire

I have a parent view **edit.blade.php** which has a form. The form has a @livewire() for **edit-step.blade.php**, the child component.

**edit-step.blade.php** has a foreach loop that renders the input fields. At one point, foreach will loop three <kbd>input</kbd> fields. The submit button is in the parent view **edit.blade.php**. On submitting, data from the last input field is the only one being submitted. How do I make data from all the input fields be submitted ?

**edit.blade.php** file:

```
    <form method="post" action="{{route('todo.update', $todo->id)}}" class="py-5">
        @csrf
        @method('patch')
        <div class="py-1"><input type="text" name="title" value="{{$todo->title}}" class="py-2 px-2 border rounded" placeholder="Title" /></div>
        <div class="py-1">
            <textarea name="description" class="p-2 rounded border" placeholder="Description">{{$todo->description}}</textarea>
        </div>
        <div class="py-2">
            @livewire('edit-step', ['steps' => $todo->steps])
        </div>
        <div class="py-1"><input type="submit" value="Update" class="p-2 border rounded" /></div>
    </form>
```

**edit-step.blade.php** file:

```
    @foreach($steps as $step)
        <div class="flex justify-center py-2" wire:key="{{$loop->index}}" >
            
            <input type="text" name="step_" class="py-1 px-2 border rounded" placeholder="{{ 'Describe Step '.($loop->index + 1) }}" @if ( is_object($step) ) value="{{ $step->name }}" @endif />
            
            
            <span class="fas fa-times text-red-400 p-2" wire:click="remove({{$loop->index}})"/>
        </div>
    @endforeach
```

Comment: here is an example of multistep form using livewire. http://www.ascsoftwares.com/technology/multi-step-form-using-livewire/?ref=BestOfLaravel.com

Answer (score 1):

Here is an example from my recent project. I have managed this with a single livewire component.
In Livewire Component;

```
public $entries = [];
public $date;

public function mount()
{
   $this->date = now()->format('Y-m-d');

   $this->entries=[
    [
     'name'=>'',
     'amount'=>'',
    ],
    [
     'name'=>'',
     'amount'=>'',
    ]
 }
```

Now, in `edit.blade.php` ;

```
<input type="date" wire:model="date">

@foreach($entries as $key=>$entry)
<div wire:key="{{'entry'.$key}}">
  <div>
   <input type="text" wire:model="entries.{{$key}}.name">
  </div>
  <div>
   <input type="number" wire:model="entries.{{$key}}.amount">
  </div>
</div>
@endforeach
```

Now, again in livewire component for saving;

```
public function save()
{
  foreach($this->entries as $entry){
    Transaction::create([
      'name'=>$entry['name'],
      'amount'=>$entry['amount']
    )];
  }
  //Notify User
}
```

However, if for any reason you need two livewire component to manage a same form, you can emit from a component and listen in another component.
For example in emitting component;

```
public function save(){
   $this->emit('entryMade', $amount);
}
```

Now in listening component;

```
protected $listeners = ['entryMade'];

public function entryMade($amount)
{
  // Do anything with $amount
}
```